# How to set CUMULATE window params in processing time?

Tags: apache-flink

My Flink version is 1.15.0

Here is the source table ddl:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE source_table (
    // ... non-important columns
    // ...
    proctime AS PROCTIME()  -- run on processing-time
);
```

and create a cumulate window like below, use column `proctime` as window time split descriptor.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_view AS
SELECT
...
FROM TABLE(CUMULATE(TABLE source_table, DESCRIPTOR(proctime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES, INTERVAL '1' DAYS))
GROUP BY window_start, window_end;
```

But it throw an exception when compile:

> The window function requires the timecol is a time attribute type, but is TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE(3)

I've realized that `PROCTIME()` function return type is `TIMESTAMP_LTZ`, but how to cast this to valid value? I tried to use `CAST(proctime AS TIMESTAMP) as proctime` but it's still incorrect and throw exception as below.

> The window function requires the timecol is a time attribute type, but is TIMESTAMP(6).

I've change the field name `proctime` to `pro_time` or something else and works. Thank for help.

Comment: Which Flink version are you using?

Comment: Perhaps you have confused the planner by using the name of the proctime() function as the attribute name? Maybe try changing the field name to something else.